# find about center of G s.t H is normal subgroup of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let G be a finite group and H be normal subgroup of order 2. Then order of center of G is

1. 0
2. 1
3. Even integer $\ge $2
4. Odd integer $\ge $3

I tried this problem by taking G as $S_3$ and H as $ A_3$, therefore as we know center of $ S_n$ for any n is 1. Therefore answer is 1.

But in book answer is option 3. Is there any way to find center and its order under the conditions that I am missing?

Comment: Note that $S_3$ doesn't have a normal subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: Oh A_n has index 2, not order 2. Correct

Answer (score 9):

A group of order $2$ contains one nonidentity element. For $H$, call this element $x$. Then for all $y\in G$ we have $yxy^{-1}=x$ since $H$ is normal. Thus $yx=xy$, so $x$ commutes with every element of $G$, hence is in the center. Since the center has an element of order $2$, it must be of even order.

Comment: The last line is unclear to me. "If center has element of order 2, then it must be of even order"?is it bcoz order of elemnt divides order of group?

Comment: @singularity Yes. You could also say that since the center contains a subgroup of order 2 then its order must be even.

Comment: @MattSamuel You have written center has element of order 2. How did you determine that x has order 2

Comment: @Taylor for the anniversary of the question eh? $x$ is the nonidentity element of $H$, hence has order $2$. It is invariant under conjugation because $H$ is normal, hence it is in the center.

Comment: @MattSamuel i was going to ask same question and i found it has been already asked before. i do not know about conjugation. is it because since order of element divided prder of group and identity has 0 order so order of other element must be 2, since group is of order 2

Comment: @Taylor this can be deduced by direct calculation (there's only one thing $x^2$ can be for it to satisfy the group axioms) or by Lagrange's theorem, which implies that the order of an element must divide the order of the group. Only the identity has order 1, so $x$ must have order 2.

Comment: @Taylor looking more closely at your question (it's late) you need to know about conjugation to know the definition of a normal subgroup. In general conjugating $y$ by $z$ gives $zyz^{-1}$...

Comment: @Taylor and if you do this to all elements of a normal subgroup they'll stay inside the subgroup. This explains why $x$ is in the center as in the answer.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks

Comment: @Taylor no problem.